# DDL Trigger execution error on schema changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created DDL triggers for SQL Server. After doing some DDL operations like create/alter/drop table, i am getting this following error - 'An error was raised during trigger execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if any, has been rolled back'. Can anyone help me with it.

Here is the trigger creation script -

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [tr_SCHEMA_CHANGES]
ON DATABASE
FOR DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SCHEMA_CHANGES') IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
      DECLARE @Eventdata XML;
      SET @Eventdata = EVENTDATA();
      INSERT dbo.SCHEMA_CHANGES (
       [DateTime]
      , [ServerName]
      , [ServiceName]
      , [SPID]
      , [SourceHostName]
      , [LoginName]
      , [UserName]
      , [SchemaName]
      , [TABLE_NAME]
      , [TargetObjectName]
      , [EVENT_TYPE]
      , [ObjectType]
      , [TargetObjectType]
      , [EventData]
      , [COMMAND_TEXT]
      , [ReplicationAuditId]
      , [ReplicationOperation]
      , [ReplicationDateTime]
      , [RowState]
            
      )
      VALUES (
       GETUTCDATE()
      , @@SERVERNAME
      , @@SERVICENAME
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]', 'int')
      , HOST_NAME()
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectName)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TargetObjectType)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)')
      , @Eventdata
      , @Eventdata.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]', 'nvarchar(MAX)')
      , 0
      ,'Schema Replication'
      , GETUTCDATE()
      ,'queued'
      );
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
      SET @Eventdata= NULL;
    END CATCH
  END
END
GO

ENABLE TRIGGER [tr_SCHEMA_CHANGES] ON DATABASE
GO
```

Tried with changes script but same error

Comment: Change this in the catch  `SET @Eventdata = EVENTDATA();
PRINT @Eventdata` And show us what you get

Comment: Remove the `TRY .. CATCH` (it's currently doing nothing but swallowing any error without a chance for feedback) and add `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the top for more consistent error reporting.